# Multiplatform MBaas similar to CloudKit?

Tags: android, parse-platform, azure-mobile-services, cloudkit

I need to implement my CloudKit based app in Android too.

Which MBaas has the most similar architecture like CloudKit? I need these features:

- cascade deletes
- able to track insert / update / delete changes in tables up from a date represented with a token
- asset management
- cursor based record fetching / paging, skip
- scalable (no join like operation need / should be possible)
- able to get push notification about changes
- reasonable pricing for startups
- cloud based
- no server side logic
- don't offer client side storage, I have it
- simple dashboard / no performance graphs etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to use CloudKit from android is by creating an OS X app that will act like a web service to which the android devices can connect. The OS X app would then pass on that query to CloudKit. I'm not really sure if that would be possible since an OS X app can only connect to CloudKit if it's in the AppStore.

Other popular services that are used for data storage and push notifications are:

- [parse](https://parse.com)
- [Windows Azure mobile services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/)
- [AWS mobile services](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/)
- [Mobile Solutions on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-application-solutions/)

And some less popular:

- [CloudMine](https://cloudmine.me/platform-features)
- [Appcelerator](https://www.appcelerator.com/product/)
- [App42](http://api.shephertz.com)

I have played around with Azure and AWS but those are far from the easy experience that you have using CloudKit. Google seems to be even more work. I have not played with parse, but what I read and see for demo's it's the easiest to use out of these 4.

If anyone else knows other technology that could fit the list above, then let us know so that we can add it.

Comment: after searching I also found this one: https://cloudmine.me/platform-features but it does not look like it's very open.

Comment: Appcelerator would also give you these features, but then you would be very tight up to their product (and you need to change your entire appdevelopment) https://www.appcelerator.com/product/

Comment: article says how CloudKit can use from cross platform solution called Xamarin, do you think app compiled to Android too, will able store data in CloudKit? http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/intro_to_cloudkit/

Comment: One of the first lines there is: 'iCloud APIs enable iOS 8 applications to store data in iCloud' so I guess the answer is no. Xamarin is a multi platform development tool. It looks like it's possible to use a platform specific API

Answer (score 0):

**Parse**

- cascade delete, called [afterDelete Triggers][1] - OK
- cursor based record fetching / paging, skip - OK
- able to track changes in tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151103/is-parse-able-to-notify-track-changes-in-tables - not really

---

I think the right workaround is to do it by yourself: You can start it here: https://github.com/j4nos/REST-Node.js-MongoDB-OpenShift