# Does parse has foreign keys to do cascade deletes?

Tags: parse-platform

Does parse has a 'foreign key' / 'reference' like feature? Can a delete self relationship created between records? So if one of the record is deleted other will be automatically deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you have to handle this by yourself.

I suggest using the -`afterDelete` in cloudcode

[Link 1](https://parse.com/questions/on-delete-cascade-equivalent-for-parse--2)

[Link 2](https://www.parse.com/questions/newb-trying-to-cascade-deletes)

Comment: Dear Janos;  Zil is faster than me and Zil is right. You can use afterDelete cloud functions.

Comment: Yeah I put the turbo on so I can reach 1.1k :D

Comment: `afterDelete` is something else .. can't delete structures

Comment: unfortunatelly so parse.com failed my competition find the best multiplatform MBaas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818527/multiplatform-mbaas-similar-to-cloudkit/29890990#29890990